# WinError 32 keeps occuring when running script, even when a temporary directory is created. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, gis, arcgis

I am currently trying to write a python script that creates a backup of a ArcGIS Online Layer, but I keep getting the WinError 32 with this code and basically any script I run. I was having this issue before so I thought that making a temporary directory would help but the issue is still happening, I am not completely confident in knowing how directories work though so I may just be putting in unrelated code. The code I am currently using is as follows (also note I am very very new to coding):

```
# create a temporary directory since I keep getting a file in use error but this also doesnt fix it lol
import tempfile
 
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
     print('created temporary directory', tmpdir)
 
# Import necessary modules
import arcgis
from arcgis.gis import GIS
 
# Create a GIS object
gis = GIS("insert_link", "username", "password")
 
# Get the item that represents the layer that you want to copy
layer_item = gis.content.get("layer_ID")
 
# Create a copy of the layer
copy_item = layer_item.copy()
 
# Find any old copies of the layer and delete them
for item in gis.content.search(query="title:'Copy of {}'".format(layer_item.title)):
    if item.type == "Feature Layer":
        item.delete()
 
# Save the new copy of the layer
copy_item.save()
# one day I will see this
print("File Downloaded")
```

This is the error I get:

```
C:\Users\SeanW\anaconda3\envs\MeganScriptTests\python.exe C:\Users\SeanW\PycharmProjects\AGOLBackup3\main.py 
created temporary directory C:\Users\SeanW\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj0yvbg64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SeanW\anaconda3\envs\MeganScriptTests\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 92, in _tempfile
    os.write(fd, reader())
  File "C:\Users\SeanW\anaconda3\envs\MeganScriptTests\lib\importlib\abc.py", line 371, in read_bytes
    with self.open('rb') as strm:
  File "C:\Users\SeanW\anaconda3\envs\MeganScriptTests\lib\importlib\_adapters.py", line 54, in open
    raise ValueError()
ValueError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SeanW\PycharmProjects\AGOLBackup3\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import arcgis
  File "C:\Users\SeanW\anaconda3\envs\MeganScriptTests\lib\site-packages\arcgis\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from arcgis.auth.tools import LazyLoader
  File "C:\Users\SeanW\anaconda3\envs\MeganScriptTests\lib\site-packages\arcgis\auth\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .api import EsriSession
  File "C:\Users\SeanW\anaconda3\envs\MeganScriptTests\lib\site-packages\arcgis\auth\api.py", line 11, in <module>
    certifi_win32.wincerts.verify_combined_pem()
  File "C:\Users\SeanW\anaconda3\envs\MeganScriptTests\lib\site-packages\certifi_win32\wincerts.py", line 65, in verify_combined_pem
    with open(certifi_pem()) as certifi_pem_handle:
  File "C:\Users\SeanW\anaconda3\envs\MeganScriptTests\lib\site-packages\certifi_win32\wincerts.py", line 52, in certifi_pem
    import certifi
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\SeanW\anaconda3\envs\MeganScriptTests\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 177, in _exec_module
    notify_module_loaded(module)
  File "C:\Users\SeanW\anaconda3\envs\MeganScriptTests\lib\site-packages\wrapt\decorators.py", line 470, in _synchronized
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SeanW\anaconda3\envs\MeganScriptTests\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 136, in notify_module_loaded
    hook(module)
  File "C:\Users\SeanW\anaconda3\envs\MeganScriptTests\lib\site-packages\certifi_win32\wrapt_certifi.py", line 20, in apply_patches
    certifi_win32.wincerts.CERTIFI_PEM = certifi.where()
  File "C:\Users\SeanW\anaconda3\envs\MeganScriptTests\lib\site-packages\certifi\core.py", line 72, in where
    _CACERT_PATH = str(_CACERT_CTX.__enter__())
  File "C:\Users\SeanW\anaconda3\envs\MeganScriptTests\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\SeanW\anaconda3\envs\MeganScriptTests\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 98, in _tempfile
    _os_remove(raw_path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\SeanW\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpx9og0v3t'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried python 3.11 as well but it gives me another error where it cannot open an orphan path and I could find nothing about that online. I have also tried this on another computer in case my python was configured wrong and the same issue occurred. I have read it may be the python-certifi-win32 package but the same error occurs when I try to uninstall it. Indenting the code after making a temp directory also does not fix the winerror 32 issue.

Comment: Please [edit] the code directly into your question as a code block. We're not going to go off-site to read it.

Comment: I have just done so I was scared of breaking the post at first.

Comment: Can you make a [mre]? So remove **every** line that is not needed to reproduce this error. Then also include the **exact** traceback message, so we can see at which line the error occurs. If I understand you correctly, the error was already present _before_ adding `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()`, so then this line is _not_ causing the problem and only misleading.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory` as a context manager (using `with`):

```py
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
    print('created temporary directory', tmpdir)
```

[When used this way](https://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory), the directory gets deleted automatically at the end of the indented block:

> On completion of the context or destruction of the temporary directory object, the newly created temporary directory and all its contents are removed from the filesystem.

Whatever you want to do in the temporary directory needs to happen inside the indented block.

Comment: Alternatively, forget about the context manager and just do `tmpdir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()`.

Comment: Yes, in which case it will be your responsibility to clean up later, assuming that's what is desired.

Comment: Same issue still occurs when trying both indents and the version without auto-deletion, which doesnt make sense to me since that seems like a perfect fix.

Comment: @Sean, the code you show in your question doesn't appear to do anything with the temporary directory. You create one, then it gets cleaned up, then there's a bunch of other code that does something completely different. What are you trying to accomplish using a temporary directory with all that GIS code? Please update your question with details.

Comment: Just updated it, sorry I am new enough to where I am not always sure what info is relevant.